# Redefine block template for Beamer theorem-like environment

Tags: beamer, theorems

I would like to redefine the block templates for Beamer's theorem-like environments.  For example, the `example` environment creates an `exampleblock`.  I would like to make the `definition` environment do the same thing.

It's possible to do this locally using the `exampleblock` environment:

```
\begin{exampleblock}{Definition}
(Definition here)
\end{exampleblock}
```

However, I would like a global solution.

I should add that much the same question was asked [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600355/how-do-i-change-the-block-template-for-specific-theorem-environments-latex-beam), but no one seems to have figured out a solution.

Comment: So you want the `definition` environment to behave exactly as an `exampleblock`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `theorem begin` and `theorem end` templates to use an `exampleblock`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \begin{exampleblock}
  {%
%    \inserttheoremheadfont% uncomment if you want amsthm-like formatting
    \inserttheoremname
    \inserttheoremnumber
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
    \inserttheorempunctuation
  }%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{exampleblock}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
Test text.
\end{definition}
\begin{exampleblock}{Definition}
(Definition here)
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above solution makes all theorem-like environments inherit the settings for `exampleblock`; if just the default `definition` environment must behave like `exampleblock`, all one has to do is to change the default style used for `definition` to make it equal to the `example` style; a simple way to achieve this is to `\let` both commands `\definition` and `\enddefinition` to `\relax` and then use `\newtheorem` to define the definition structure using the `example` style.

An example showing this approach; `definition` behaves as an `exampleblock`, but all other theorem-like structures preserve theis default behaviour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\let\definition\relax
\let\enddefinition\relax

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\translate{Definition}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
Test text.
\end{definition}
\begin{exampleblock}{Definition}
Test text.
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{theorem}
Test text.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution changes all theorem environments.  I would like to make `definition` into an `exampleblock`, but leave the other theorem environments unchanged.

Comment: @AndrewUzzell please see my updated answer.