# redefine theorem environment with beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

beamer seems to define theorem-environments such as `definition`, but i want to be able to define them myself. In particular I want to use thmtools.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[style=definition]{definition}

\begin{document}
\title{thmtools + beamer}
\date{\today}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Compiling this yields

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \definition already defined.
```

but I could not find anything like a `\redeclaretheorem` command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefine block template for Beamer theorem-like environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71265/redefine-block-template-for-beamer-theorem-like-environment)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can undefine it before defining it

```
\let\definition\relax
\theoremstyle{definition}
```